# Sortable bootstrap table with rails gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [bootstrap-table-rails gem](https://github.com/bjevanchiu/bootstrap-table-rails) to create sortable ability to my table. It works fine except when I change data in table's field via JS. 
My code looks like this:

```
<table data-toggle="table" class="table table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="date" data-sortable="true">TITLE</th>
            <th data-field="deadline" data-sortable="true">DEADLINE</th>
            <th data-field="accept-job" data-sortable="true"></th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>Sample data</td>
             <td>Sample data</td>
             <td class="accept_field"><button class="btn accept_btn">Accept Job</button></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Sample data</td>
             <td>Sample data</td>
             <td>Sample data</td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Basically this table contains two rows, one of them is filled with dummy data, other is filled with dynamic data (`deadline_field`). I change data via JS like this:

```
function Timer(duration, display, deadline) {
    var timer = duration, hours, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        hours = parseInt((timer /3600)%24, 10)
        minutes = parseInt((timer / 60)%60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
        deadline.text(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
        --timer;
    }, 1000);
};

$(".accept-btn").click(function() {
    var twentyFourHours = 24 * 60 * 60;
    // Show timer element on page
    var display = $('.countdown').show();
    var deadline = $('.deadline_field');
    Timer(twentyFourHours, display, deadline);
});
```

This function does the following:
1. It counts time from 24 hours.
2. It displays deadline on other page and in table, `deadline_field`. It works just fine, but when I try to sort table, `deadline_field` value is being changed to `Sample data`, i.e sort doesn't work no more.
I would highly appreciate any thoughts about this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of researching I decided to switch to [sorttable.js](https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) plugin which works just fine to me.